# Function to fetch a generic collection from Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch a collection from Firestore using a generic function, I used to use a this function that works only for one Object in this case `ModelUser`:

```
Future<ModelUser?> readUser(String userID) async {
  ModelUser? modelUser;
  await _db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userID)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      try {
        //Names ModelUser should match with database names
        modelUser = ModelUser.fromJson(documentSnapshot.data()!);
        print('readUser');
        Get.i.put<ModelUser>(modelUser);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        modelUser = null;
      }
    } else {
      modelUser = null;
    }
  });
  return modelUser;
}
```

However, I need a function to avoid repeating code using a generic function and passing the collection I will need. I'm trying with this function but I can't figure out how to complete the function right now, all my Models objects have the factory method fromJson, this part is where I have the error because The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'. Maybe there is a way to use a generic factory method to use it in this function.

```
Future<T?> readObjectCollection<T>(
    String userID, String collectionName) async {
  T? modelCollection;
  await _db
      .collection(collectionName)
      .doc(userID)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      try {

        //Names Object should match with database names
        modelCollection = T.fromJson(documentSnapshot.data()!);

        Get.i.put<T>(modelCollection);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        modelCollection = null;
      }
    } else {
      modelCollection = null;
    }
  });
  return modelCollection;
}
```

I already tried passing the complete factory function as a parameter, but there was some errors because this function need a Map that should be passed when the method is defined, also passing the object I'm going to use as a parameter, but passing the object and using its method `fromJson` return always null.

If someone can see where I'm making a mistake or have another way to achieve this goal please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this gives you insight:

```
Future readObjectCollection<T>(
    String userID, String collectionName) async {
  var modelCollection;
  await _db
      .collection(collectionName)
      .doc(userID)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      try {

        //Names Object should match with database names
        if(T is ModelUser){
        modelCollection = ModelUser.fromJson(documentSnapshot.data()!);
       }

        Get.i.put<T>(modelCollection);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        modelCollection = null;
      }
    } else {
      modelCollection = null;
    }
  });
  return modelCollection;
}
```